# SQL Server - SQL Compare - Automatic identification and replacement of differing database names?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcompare

**I have two development databases locally**

1. `Alpha`
2. `Beta_Dev`

**I have two production databases remotely**

1. `Alpha`
2. `Beta`

**I use [SQL Compare](http://www.google.com/search?q=sql%20compare&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=vNx&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&source=hp&q=%22sql%20compare%22%20&aq=f&aqi=g5&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=5014d35bb6efb157&biw=1920&bih=953) to sync the schema of the two Alpha databases.**

Sometimes, stored procedures in the Development version of Database `Alpha` reference tables in Database `Beta`, or in the local environment, `Beta_Dev`.

For Example:

```
Select * from Beta_Dev.dbo.MyTable
```

This code will not work on the production server, because the Beta Database is called `Beta`, rather than `Beta_Dev`.

**Is there a way, using SQL Compare, to have all SP's or Views be compared such that `Beta_Dev (local) = Beta (remote)`?**

Not only would the databases be uploaded in working order, but SQL Compare won't be tricked into thinking the SP's are different, when only Beta_Dev / Beta are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it the way you want but here is a potential workaround if it is suitable for what you want to do

Create `Synonyms` for the objects that are reference in the `Beta` databases

```
USE [Alpha]
CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[BetaMyTable] FOR [Beta].[dbo].[MyTable]
```

and

```
USE [Alpha_dev]
CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[BetaMyTable] FOR [Beta_dev].[dbo].[MyTable]
```

so your procs can now use:

```
SELECT * FROM BetaMyTable
```

in SQL Compare, there is an ignore rule option in `Edit Project... -> Options` called `Database and server name in synonyms`. I believe it is checked by default but it is there if you want to change it